# Force a .NET test method to fail from the inside

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Most of my test methods first try two or three trivial operations which should raise an exception, and then begin the real work. In Java, I would write it like this:

```
@Test
public void TestSomething() {

    try {
        testedClass.testedMethod(null);
        fail();
    catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        // OK
    }

    // and now let's get to the point ...
    // ...

}
```

I wanted to stick with this habit in C#, **but it seems there is no way to force a test method to fail**. I've been looking a round for a while, but with no luck. Have I missed something?

PS: I know the correct way of testing these situations is this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(ArgumentNullException)]
public void TestSomethingWithNull() {

    testedClass.TestedMethod(null);

}

[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething() {

   // now the non-trivial stuff...

}
```

...but, I don't like this. When I have, let's say, 6 test methods in my test class, and each of those tests should start with covering three trivial, one-line situations which should raise an exception, using this approach turns my 6 tests into 18. In a bigger application, this really pollutes my Test Explorer and makes the results more difficult to scan through.

And let's say I want to test a method, whose responsibility is to validate each property of a given instance of some class, and raise a ValidationException if any value is incorrect. That could be easily handled by one TestValidation() test, but with this approach, turns it into:

- TestValidationWithNull();
- TestValidationWithInvalidProperty1();
- TestValidationWithInvalidProperty2();
- TestValidationWithNullProperty2();

Imagine you have 20 properties... :)

Of course, if this is the only way to do it, I'll bite.

Comment: PPS: Yes, the validation method could return a bool instead of throwing exceptions upon encountering an invalid value; and this way it could be tested in one method with assertions. But that's beyond the point now. :)

Comment: Don't you want to test if the exceptions work for each property, independent of eachother? Yeah, you could all put it in one test but that defies the idea behind unit testing: it's about testing isolated requirements. Now you won't know what property causes the exception, it doesn't really matter how many tests you have.

Comment: @oli.G can you give more context about which properties do you check? Please, add one more test which checks invalid property1. Looks like I have an idea

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I have a VideoFile class which contains mostly unrealted and trivial properties like long ID, string FilePath, bool Favorite, long DurationFrames, etc. And I have a Validator.Validate<T> static method, which assures that the ID is non-negative, FilePath actually exists, DurationFrames is positive, etc. Then I just TRY inserting the entities to the DB and apart from a SQLiteException I'm also catching ValidationException. And I need a test that assures nothing invalid slips through Validator.Validate<T>

Comment: @oli.G I'd go with keeping VideoFile object away from invalid state. You can add data verification in property setters (well, except file existence check), or even make it as ValueObject with private setters. Write tests for VideoFile, and check if file exists before saving. Maybe you even don't need ID here - filePath looks like unique thing to distinguish VideoFiles

Comment: I want IDs for naming thumbnail files, but you couldn't have known that :) Looking at the code now, moving all validation to model classes' setters wouldn't be much work, I'd clean up the namespace a bit, and the model classes wouldn't be so childishly trivial anymore. Would you say this generally the way to go? Keep any instance perfectly valid and INSERT-ready all the time?

Comment: I imagine it makes absolute sense with some kind of active record pattern, but I'm not using that (never have). I'm using classes like VideoFileManager etc for CRUD. With my pattern, this looks like an interesting question for Programmers Stack Exchange - validate in every setter vs. in the manager before CRUD operatios. I wonder whether there are any actual pros and cons, or it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Assert.Fail()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.fail.aspx) or throw [`NotImplementedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if method which you are testing is not implemented yet).

But for testing if code throws exception I suggest you to use [ExpectedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx) attribute (if you are stick to MSTest) - test will fail, if exception will not be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
Assert.Fail("Optional Message");
```

or you can just throw an exception from inside the method

You should also check out the [TestCase](http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5) attribute and [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) in NUnit. These might greatly simplify your code & testing when you want to pass different parameters to a test.

Comment: Good "workaround" with raising an exception from within the test (in a world where Assert.Fail doesn't exist).. I haven't thought of that :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it's advisable to have separate test methods for all the "trivial" stuff is because an `Assert.Fail()` early in the test method may hide later problems. As you say though, lots of trivial test methods gets unwieldy all too quickly.

Remember though that `Asset.Equals` (for NUnit at least) can compare arrays. So you can change your tests to something like the following and simulationously test many aspects of the item under test, yet have visibility of all results:

```
public void TestSomething() 
{
    var result1 = false;
    try 
    {
        testedClass.testedMethod(null);
        result1 = true;
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) { }

    var result2 = SomeDetailedTest();

    var expected = new Object[] { false, 42 };
    var actual =  new Object[] { result1, result2 };
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```